# Why doesn't this code draw a triangle?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl-2

I'm very new to OpenGL and I just wrote up a section of code using SDL 2 that to my knowledge should have drawn a triangle, but this code doesn't seem to work and so I am not done learning.  I've got all the initialization code SDL 2 documentation says I need already written in, and the functions returned by dynamic loading ARE callable.  When I execute this code instead of a triangle I get a black (but cleared) window.  Why does this code not draw the triangle I want, and why is the window cleared to black by this code?  I want to know the technical details behind mainly the first question so I can depend on it later.

```
(*main_context.glViewport)(0, 0, 100, 100);
(*main_context.glBegin)(GL_TRIANGLES);
(*main_context.glColor4d)(255, 255, 255, 255);
(*main_context.glVertex3d)(1, 1, -50);
(*main_context.glVertex3d)(1, 30, 1);
(*main_context.glVertex3d)(30, 1, 1);
(*main_context.glEnd)();
(*main_context.glFinish)();
(*main_context.glFlush)();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
```

Update:

I've revised my code to include different coordinates and I got the triangle to draw, but I cannot get it to draw when farther away.  Why is that?

```
(*main_context.glVertex3d)(2, -1, 1); /* Works. */
(*main_context.glVertex3d)(2, -1, 3); /* Doesn't work. */
```

Comment: Writing `(*main_context.gl…)(…)` looks weird. Why not simply `main_context->gl…(…)`? Also dynamically loading non-extension functions makes little sense.

Comment: So I SHOULD link against an OpenGL library myself?  I can't just dynamically load everything from the random library SDL hands me?

Comment: No a triangle.  It says GL_TRIANGLES.  Not GL_TETRAHEDRON.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be confused about how `glColor4d` works... it takes double-precision floating-point, but the value **255.0** will be clamped to **1.0** during rasterization/blending. **255** would be a meaningful value if you were using `glColor4ub`, as it would be equivalent to `glColor4f (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)`.

Comment: Also, calling `glFlush (...)` immediately after `glFinish (...)` is meaningless. And neither of these two things should be necessary if you use `SDL_GL_SwapWindow (...)`, because that implies you have a double-buffered pixel format and the swap operation implicitly does one of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are setting up a projection and/or modelview matrix elsewhere in your code, it's using the default (identity matrix) transform, which is an orthographic projection with `(-1, -1)` at the bottom left and `(1, 1)` at the top right.  `glViewport` only changes the portion of the default framebuffer being rendered to, it has no bearing on the projection whatsoever.

With an orthographic projection, the Z coordinate does not affect the screen-space position of a point, except that points outside the Z clipping planes will not be rendered.  In this case, that's everything outside of `-1 <= z <= 1`.  Given that one of your points is `(1, 1, -50)`, this seems to be your problem.

Comment: `glViewport (...)` does not change the size of the framebuffer (the window system does that automatically for the default framebuffer when you resize the window). What `glViewport (...)` does is define the region of the framebuffer in which geometry maps to *after* projection and clipping. It is the final piece of the puzzle that transforms from NDC-space to window-space (WINxy), `glDepthRange (...)` affects the mapping of NDCz -> WINz and together they perform the "viewport transform."

Comment: You are definitely right about clipping though. Only points -ClipW <= ClipXYZ <= +ClipW are in the view volume (ClipW == **1.0** in this case). Every one of the points in the original triangle is outside of the viewing volume. There is no triangle produced by the intersection of these clipped points and the viewing volume.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes, technically you are correct, though since 99% of the time the viewport is set to fill the entire framebuffer, it's easier to explain to people as if they are the same (unless it's at the core of their problem).

Comment: I see, I just think it is an important distinction because if it set the framebuffer dimensions then `glViewport (...)` could be used to selectively clear portions of the screen in a subsequent call to `glClear (...)`. A lot of people assume that is the case and then cannot figure out why it does not work that way ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Good point, I changed the wording to be more accurate.  A similar problem occurs when people don't realize that geometry can be rendered outside the viewport if it's smaller than the framebuffer, the answer to both of these problems is of course `glScissor`.